# Word count on Windows shell

Tags: linux, windows, command-line, word-count

What is the Windows equivalent of the wc linux command?
I have tried

`find /c /v "" file.txt`

but it doesn't work: the format of the parameter isn't correct. I have also tried

`find --% /c /v "" file.txt`

and it does work, but when I try to use this command with other commands, it doesn't work. For example:

`sort file.txt | Unique | find --% /c /v ""`

In this way, it counts 0 words, even if the file contains more.
Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

In powershell it should be:

```
Get-Content <filename> | Measure-Object –Line
```

I'm not aware of any proper `wc` equiv in classical windows shell.

Comment: thank you! I tried this command and it works when I use it alone, but when I use it with the other commands I wrote in the first post, then it counts 0 :(

Comment: I'm not near any windows machines at the moment, so i cannot try; but judging by the "man" page; perhaps `@( $( foreach ($line in Get-Content C:\test.txt) { $line.tolower().split(" ") }) | Sort-Object | Get-Unique ).length`